# Edit font to vertically center glyphs

Tags: fonts

I would like to edit a web font to adjust the alignment so that capital letters and numbers are exactly vertically centered. All glyphs of that height should have the same number of pixels above and below.

I'm looking for instructions on how to do this automatically using free software. I can use graphical programs or command-line programs and I can use Windows or Linux.

I understand that there are some limitations to this approach. Here are some I know of:

1. It will only work for fonts where all capital letters and numbers are the same height.
2. It may only be possible at certain sizes.
3. It may slightly alter the look and feel.
4. It will not work reliably with fractional scaling or zooming.

I will start with a font that is already close to being centered, so I think this modification wouldn't noticeably deform the text.

Comment: Where do you want to use this font? On a web site? Will you show small texts using this font (~100 chars)? Or many 1000s of words?

Comment: @zomega It will be used on a website. It will be used for small one-line labels in small containers where even 1-pixel misalignments are too noticeable.

Comment: Then it's probably easier to use JavaScript/CSS to get the result you want (without modifying the font file). For example you could use a canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816071/calculate-exact-character-string-height-in-javascript

Comment: But if you really want to modify the font file I personally would convert it to a SVG font which can then be edited easily by a PHP/Python/... script.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to use CSS in the end. I wanted to do it at the font level so that it would require less manual adjustment.